# Convert datetime to "Europe/Paris"

Tags: datetime, pandas, timezone, pytz

I have a data frame (df) with the following dateTime variable
I have to convert this time format to "Europe/Paris"

```
dateTime  
2016-05-13 00:00:00
2016-06-14 00:00:01
2016-07-15 12:32:02
2016-05-16 02:34:10
2016-05-17 11:00:04
```

I have tried the following

```
import datetime,pytz

df['EUTime'] = None
df['EUTime'] = pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris").localize(df['dateTime'], is_dst=None)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: if this is already a datetime then you can do `df['dateTime'].dt.tz_localize("Europe/Paris")` if not then convert first `df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime']).dt.tz_localize("Europe/Paris")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to convert to `datetime` dtype first, if so use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'])
```

Then you can use [`dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html):

```
In [50]:
s = s.dt.tz_localize("Europe/Paris")
s

Out[50]:
0   2016-05-13 00:00:00+02:00
1   2016-06-14 00:00:01+02:00
2   2016-07-15 12:32:02+02:00
3   2016-05-16 02:34:10+02:00
4   2016-05-17 11:00:04+02:00
Name: dateTime  , dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]
```